# Removing duplicate items from a ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, duplicates, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` with 10 items like this:

```
1:3
2:2
2:2
2:2
1:3
6:8
6:8
9:1
7:2
9:1
```

I want to remove duplicates so the result looks like this:

```
1:3
2:2
6:8
9:1
7:2
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++)
    {
        a[p] = System.Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox("Please Enter 10 Number:", "", "", 350, 350));
        listBox1.Items.Add(a[p]);
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            if (a[j] == a[k])
                b = b + 1;
        } //end of for (k)
        listBox2.Items.Add(a[j] + ":" + b);
        b = 0;
    } //end og for (j)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        List<string> p = new List<string>();

        p.Add("1:2");
        p.Add("1:4");
        p.Add("1:3");
        p.Add("1:2");

        List<string> z = p.Distinct().ToList();
```

Here is the easiest way to do it. Instead of direct `listBox.Items.Add(value)` add the values in `List<string>` and add it as DataSource of the listBox. You will perform `Distinct()` action before putting the `DataSource`. If this is asp.net you need `listBox.DataBind()` after that.

**Edit**:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            if (a[j] == a[k])
                b = b + 1;
        } //end of for (k)
        list.Add(a[j] + ":" + b);
        b = 0;
    } //end og for (j)

    List<string> result = list.Distinct().ToList();
    listBox2.DataSource = result;
    //listBox2.DataBind(); this is needed if it is asp.net, if it is winforms it is not needed !
}
```

Comment: how can i clean listbox items?
listBox2.Items.Clear(); does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
    listBox1.Items.CopyTo(arr, 0);

    var arr2 = arr.Distinct();

    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string s in arr2)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```